# How to use of WIF token in an applicaiton(workload) running outside gcp ? e.g Quarkus app onprem putting messages to pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, quarkus, google-authentication

I have a utility to get WIF-token for a service account sa1 :
e.g getWif(idp.client, idp.secret, gcp.projNum, "sa1@projx.iam.gsrviceaccount.com", "myIdpPool", "myIdpApp")

I set that wif/access token in env variable and start my quarkus application (outside gcp, e.g laptop, or onpremserver)

Questions:

1. Is this the "right way" to make use of WIF-token for apps running outside GCP?
2. Is there some utility/feature in gcp-libraries to refresh the wif token if necessary? E.g Hooking a token-refresher function to com.google.api.gax.core.CredentialsProvider

```sh
# This is wif-access-token of service account
# GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN=myutility.getWif(idp.client, idp.secret, gcp.projNum, "sa1@projx.iam.gsrviceaccount.com", "myIdpPool", "myIdpApp")
export GOOGLE_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN="ya29.c.NNNN..."

#start the quarkus app in laptop , or in an onprem server
mvn quarkus:dev
```

Goal : get put messages to pubsub. Using that WIF-access token.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever possible, [use the Google Cloud client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-workload-identity-federation#generate-automatic) to do the authentication for you. The `google-auth-library-oauth2-http` library [supports workload identity federation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-workload-identity-federation#java) as of version `0.24.0` and can automatically exchange and refresh tokens.

If you can't use the client libraries (for example, because it's not compatible with your identity provider), then you'll need to write some custom code to let your Quarkus service periodically fetch and refresh tokens. [The steps to do this are described in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/using-workload-identity-federation#authenticating_by_using_the_rest_api).

Comment: I'm able to get SUBJECT_TOKEN -> STS_TOKEN -> ACCESS_TOKEN.  How do I make use of that ACCESS_TOKEN in java, to get/put mesages in pubsub?

Comment: You can check on this, it might help you on pushing messages in pub/sub. https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher.